# What technique's can be used to identify and count individual animals in a dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, unsupervised-learning, feature-extraction

Problem:

I have an image dataset that contains a lot of different chitals (a species of deer). The images are taken by cameratraps in a National Park. I would like to count the individual animals.

For example, if I have 1000 images of chitals, I could have a maximum of 1000 individual chitals. This could also be less, let us say 500, if every chital is captured twice in the dataset. So, I do not have any labels, only the images.

I thought about using feature descriptors, but I do not know how to apply them to this problem.

Question:

What techniques can be used for counting individual chitals? Giving some keywords would also help me in the right direction.

Comment: The neerest thing would probably be facial recognition. Seems like a very hard problem. I am not sure you can get out of it without labelling the pictures first.

Comment: Take a look at weakly supervised object localization. This techinque aims to localize objects with only image-level labels.